# Ajaxed loaded content doesn't behave as it should

Tags: php, wordpress, jquery, contact-form-7

There is a page template called `post-plain-body` that prints the title and body of the post passed. The page named `AjaxLoader` uses this template. If for example I call `/ajaxloader` with `id` as a `$_POST['id']` value, the contents of that post will be displayed.

This is called via jQuery on the main page. It actually loads the contents of a post/page to a specific context.

One of the pages I load, contains a `Contact Form 7` form. The form is displayed but when I submit it, it goes to a `/ajaxloader/#wpcf7-f2-p34-o1` instead of using Ajax to validate the form.

This is the page template.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Ajax Loader
*/

// Load contact form 7 scripts
if ( function_exists( 'wpcf7_enqueue_scripts' ) ) {
    wpcf7_enqueue_scripts();
    wpcf7_enqueue_styles();
}

// Gets the content only from a post. Used in ajax loading
if(isset($_POST['id'])):
    $post = get_post($_POST['id']);
    if ($post) : setup_postdata($post); 
        ?>
        <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div><?php
    endif;
else:?>
    <h2>Page not found</h2><?php
endif;
?>
```

And the jQuery that is loading the content is the following

```
function load_page(pid) {
    $("#page_preview").load("ajaxloader/", {id:pid},function(){
        $('#page_preview').fadeIn(300);
        $('#page_loading').hide();
    });
}
```

**EDIT**

The `<form>` isn't attached to the Contact Form 7 scripts as it should. I found this using javascript debugging in firebug. Normally, it should have two handlers attached to `click` and `submit` events. Any suggestions why it isn't attached?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `contact-form-7` is calling `load_page()` function upon submit. You might want to check how you have defined the event handler that is calling `load_page()`.

It might also be that `contact form 7` uses a function of the same name `load_page()` and causing some conflicts.

You should give us the weighted down version on jsfiddle.

Comment: The form is submited after it has been validated. When I submit it, it loads the `/ajaxloader` without the validation. Although the problem is that it goes to another page, it is more important to find the reason it doesn't validate. I am thinking of jquery conflicts.

Comment: @Odys - Well... try using breakpoints and firebug to see step by step execution of js to find the problem if you can't give us the source on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Might seem trivial to somebody, but anyway I thought I should share.

On page templates that you use to load content only (no headers, sidebars etc) using Ajax, do the following:

1. add `wp_head();`
2. add the page template (as in the question above)
3. add `wp_footer();` to the bottom

If somebody has more info on the procedure, please contribute :)

Answer (score 0):

Call this on AjaxComplete:

```
var ajaxContainer = $('#somediv_id'),
    newCF7 = $('.wpcf7 > form', ajaxContainer);
    newCF7.attr('action', "#" + newCF7.attr('id'));
    wpcf7.initForm( newCF7 );
```